# Error while installing SSL in Apache

Tags: apache, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

**I am following these steps for SSL :**

```
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout domain.key -out domain.crt
```

This works fine.

```
openssl req -text -noout -verify -in domain.crt
```

Works good.

```
openssl rsa -in domain.key -check

> RSA key ok writing RSA key
> -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
> 
> 
> .....
> 
> 
> -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Move `.key` and `.crt` file to `/etc/apache2/ssl`

Open `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf`

Add

```
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile      /etc/apache2/ssl/domain.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/domain.key
```

Next is

```
sudo a2enmod ssl

sudo service apache2 restart
```

**Error is::**

```
[Wed Jun 13 10:48:03.690496 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 2536] AH02562: Failed to configure certificate 172.31.25.100:443:0 (with chain), check /etc/apache2/ssl/domain.crt
    [Wed Jun 13 10:48:03.690538 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 2536] SSL Library Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line (Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE) -- Bad file contents or format - or even just a forgotten SSLCertificateKeyFile?
    [Wed Jun 13 10:48:03.690548 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 2536] SSL Library Error: error:140DC009:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file:PEM lib
    AH00016: Configuration Failed
```

Comment: You haven't signed the certificate. A CSR is not a certificate. Off topic.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to install ssl automatically. You can do it this by only some codes:

```
sudo apt-get install git

git clone https://github.com/letsencrypt/letsencrypt

cd letsencrypt/

./letsencrypt-auto
```

After this it will ask you to accept the terms and if you want to redirect all traffic from http to https. so, you have to read carefully.